# How to print a string of variables without spaces in Python (minimal coding!)

Tags: python, printing, stdout

I have something like : `print "\n","|",id,"|",var1,"|",var2,"|",var3,"|",var4,"|"`

It prints with spaces for each variable.

```
| 1 | john | h | johnny | mba |
```

I want something like this :

```
|1|john|h|johnny|mba|
```

I have 20 variables that I have to print and I hate use sys.stdout.write(var) for each one of them. Thanks Pythonistas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `join`:

```
print "\n"+'|'.join([id,var1,var2,var3,var4])
```

or if the variables aren't already strings:

```
print "\n"+'|'.join(map(str,[id,var1,var2,var3,var4]))
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to build a long format string and it basically works unchanged for an arbitrary number of variables.

Answer (score 7):

For a variable number of values:

```
print '|%s|' % '|'.join(str(x) for x in [id, var1, var2, var3, var4])
```

Comment: print '|%s|' % '|'.join(map(str, [id, var1, var2, var3, var4])) looks better (if you have really big array you can use imap instead).

Comment: @Tomasz: You think so? I thought that Pythonistas normally consider the generator clearer...

Comment: You may be right. But in this approach map seams to be useless.

Answer (score 5):

```
print "\n|%s|%s|%s|%s" % (id,var1,var2,var3,var4)
```

Take a look at [String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).

Edit: The other answers with join are better. Join expects strings.

Comment: `%s` works with any object, not just strings -- `"%s + %s" % (1, 2) == "1 + 2"`. You don't have to use `%d` unless you want the code to throw an exception for non-numeric input.

Comment: Of course %s doesn't give terribly useful output unless `__str__` or `__repr__` are implemented

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2.6 or newer, use the new standard for formating string, the str.format method:

```
print "\n{0}|{1}|{2}|".format(id,var1,var2)
```

[link text](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: And if you have Python 2.7 or newer, you can even drop the numbers: `"\n{}|{}|{}|".format(id, var1,var2)`