# How to remove space in python 2.7.5

Tags: python, string, formatting

When I use the code in python 2.7.5

```
for i in [1,2]:
       print 'distance',':400@CA',':',i,'@CA'
```

I got the following

```
distance :400@CA : 1 @CA

distance :400@CA : 2 @CA
```

I want to remove the space (eg., among :,1,@CA) so that the output will be like

```
distance :400@CA :1@CA

distance :400@CA :2@CA
```

I also tried using sep='' or end='' but still they don't work. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [string formatting operator `%`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
for i in [1,2]:
   print 'distance :400@CA :%d@CA' % i
```

This gives you quite a lot of control over how things are laid out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use %d operator:

```
for i in [1,2]:
       print 'distance',':400@CA',':','%d@CA' % i
```

Or you can use join:

```
for i in [1,2]:
           print 'distance'+':400@CA:'.join(i,'@CA')
```

With reference to:[How to print a string of variables without spaces in Python (minimal coding!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249949/how-to-print-a-string-of-variables-without-spaces-in-python-minimal-coding)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
  for i in [1,2]:
           print 'distance',':400@CA',':'+str(i)+'@CA'

Output: distance :400@CA :1@CA
        distance :400@CA :2@CA
```

Using ,(comma) will add space while printing. Better concatenate using +

Answer (score 0):

Use the sep tag in print

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('distance',':400@CA',':',i,'@CA', sep = '')
```