# Python newspace persists

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to make a name generator:

```
from random import randint
relation = {
    'A' : ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'R', 'Y'],
    'B' : ['E', 'O', 'I'],
    'C' : ['A', 'E', 'H', 'R', 'O', 'I'],
    'D' : ['A', 'E', 'H', 'R', 'O', 'I'],
    'E' : ['R', 'T', 'P', 'S', 'F', 'L', 'X'],
    'F' : ['E', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'A'],
    'G' : ['R', 'O', 'A'],
    'H' : ['E', 'I', 'O', 'A'],
    'I' : ['N', 'X', 'S', 'E', 'T', 'P', 'L', 'M'],
    'J' : ['A', 'I', 'O', 'Y'],
    'K' : ['I', 'E', 'A'],
    'L' : ['I', 'E'],
    'M' : ['O', 'Y', 'I'],
    'N' : ['E', 'I', 'O', 'A'],
    'O' : ['V', 'T', 'N'],
    'P' : ['I', 'A', 'E', 'O'],
    'Q' : ['U', 'E', 'I'],
    'R' : ['E', 'I', 'A'],
    'S' : ['T', 'I', 'O', 'A', 'H'],
    'T' : ['H', 'E', 'I'],
    'U' : ['B', 'G', 'L'],
    'V' : ['E', 'U', 'I', 'A'],
    'X' : ['I', 'O'],
    'Y' : ['E', 'L'],
    'Z' : ['O', 'I']
}
char = (raw_input("Enter an English alphabet: ")).upper()
letters = int(raw_input("How many letters: "))
for i in range(0, letters):
    if i==0:
        print char,
    else:
        print char.lower(),
    char = (relation[char])[randint(0, len(relation[char])-1)]
print ''
raw_input("Press [ENTER] to exit...")
```

But the problem is that there is a whitespace when it prints the name.
For example:

> Enter an English alphabet: T
>
> How many letters: 5
>
> T i p a y
>
> Press [ENTER] to exit...

How to remove the whitespace?

P.S: I'm a beginner :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a string of variables without spaces in Python (minimal coding!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249949/how-to-print-a-string-of-variables-without-spaces-in-python-minimal-coding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the commas that's causing this. `print` statements separated with commas add white spaces:

```
print "a", "b"
```

Prints `a b`

```
print "a",
```

Prints `a`  (with white space)

```
print "a"
```

Prints `a` (without white space)

You can, however, change your code to use a variable:

```
name = ''
for i in range(0, letters):
    if i==0:
        name += char
    else:
        name += char.lower()
    char = (relation[char])[randint(0, len(relation[char])-1)]
print name
print ''
```

Or shorter and more efficient:

```
letter_list = []
for i in range(0, letters):
    letter_list.append(char)
    char = (relation[char])[randint(0, len(relation[char])-1)]
name = ''.join(letter_list)
print name.lower().capitalize()
print ''
```

Comment: But then it will print on different lines, which is not what he wants @GreenHenk

Comment: Oh! Well now I don't know whose answer I should accept.

Comment: @heinst and GeenHenk: FWIW, building a string char by char like that is pretty inefficient in Python, since strings are immutable. It's _much_ better to store the chars in a list and then use `.join` to build a string from the list. Of course, it probably doesn't matter much for this program, but it's a good habit to get into. And although the list-based approach is a little more complicated than `name += char` it looks like Coderboy91 isn't afraid to use lists in his code. :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure your reasoning for printing as you go along, but you could have a word variable and then append all the `char` you come up with to the word variable and just print it at the end. This will not have the spaces in between the letters

```
word = ''
for i in range(0, letters):
    word += char
    char = (relation[char])[randint(0, len(relation[char])-1)]
print word.lower().capitalize()
print ''
```

Based on `PM 2 Rings` suggestion you could also do it this way:

```
charList = []
for i in range(0, letters):
    charList.append(char)
    char = (relation[char])[randint(0, len(relation[char])-1)]
print ''.join(charList).lower().capitalize()
print ''
```

Comment: @Coderboy91 Also you can use `word.lower().capitalize()` so you don't have to handle the case of each character individually.

Comment: That's OK, I like challenges ;)